# Is it possible to poll or fire an event if a class instance is created / Its method is invoked

Tags: class, events, jvm, instance, polling

I have got a requirement like, I would be receiving Class name and method names from an xml file. Now I need to do some post actions, If I got to know that specified class instance is created by JVM and and also is it possible to fire an event at tun time if its method is been invoked ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the types of events you need to fire, their context, how much control you have over the classes, and when you need to bind the handlers, there are a couple of different approaches you might take.  In your shoes, I would look first at [AspectJ](http://andrewclement.blogspot.com/2009/02/load-time-weaving-basics.html) or [CGLib](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cglib-missing-manual) and then at [Java instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).